# Use class from built jar in custom gradle task

Tags: gradle, bootstrapping

My gradle project needs to generate code for the remaining build process. The tool that should generate the code is a jar file that is also built in the same gradle project.

I want to write a custom task that handles the code generation step. This task obviously must depend on the jar file being built, this is simple enough.

Now I want to access the classes from my jar file in the custom task, and I just don't know how to tell gradle that the Parser class is available from the built jar file. See the following example for what I want to do in my task:

```
task generateCode(dependsOn: ':dmlproject:build') {

    doLast {
        DmlParser parser = new DmlParser();
        parser.doStuff();
    }  
}
```

Gradle doesn't know that the DmlParser class can be found in the dmlproject jar file, how can I tell gradle where to find it? Is that even possible?

I understand if this won't work at all before I have built the dmlproject at least once because without a jar file there is no DmlParser class either. But after the first build it should be possible to make things work, no?

**EDIT:**
Even if I cannot refer to classes in a jar file that is built in the same project, I would like to know how to access classes in a jar file on disk, or one downloaded from a maven repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original answer

If you need to write complex build logic to enhance your build, you can't do this in the main build. The reason for this is that Gradle needs to configure the project before execution starts. So Gradle needs to know the `DmlParser` class at [configuration time](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases), but your build creates it at execution time.

The way to fix this is to introduce a [`buildSrc` build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources). This is a separate build inside your project directory that you can use to implement additional complex build logic. Just create a new directory called `buildSrc` inside the project directory and move the logic that create `DmlParser` there. This way you can use the `DmlParser` in your main build.

## Edit

If you want to add a jar that has already been build, you need to use the [`buildscript` block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies) in order to add the jar to the build script's classpath:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2'
    }
}
```

Then you can refer to classes that are defined in the jars that have been added to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I was not aware of the buildSrc concept. However I still would like to know how I can refer to classes within a jar file (let's assume that the jar file is already built/downloaded from external repository)

Comment: I've extended my answer to cover this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was on the right track then, but I tried adding it as a normal project dependency and that of course did not work. I will have to treat the parser as an external component then.